# How to read a file from a folder by full file name in Perl

Tags: perl, fatal-error

I have a Perl script and I am giving the location & name of the input file and output file on the terminal

```
./R.pl  <input file>  <output file>
```

I am trying to write a Perl program which can take a file name as input and do some function and generate output in a given folder.

This is my Perl script:-

```
my $input_file = $ARGV[0]
or die "usage: $0 <input file> <output file>\n";
my $output_file = $ARGV[1]
or die "usage: $0 <input file> <output file>\n";
use File::Basename;
$fullspec = $ARGV[0];
my($files,$dir) = fileparse($fullspec);
print "Directory: " . $dir . "\n";
print "File:" . $files . "\n";
chomp($CEL_dir = $dir);
opendir (DIR, "$CEL_dir") or die "Couldn't open directory $CEL_dir";
$cel_files = $CEL_dir."/cel_files.txt";
open(CEL,">$cel_files")|| die "cannot open $file to write";
print CEL "cel_files\n";

use File::Find;

my @wanted_files;
find(
 sub{ 
     -f $_ && $_ =~ $files  
           && push @wanted_files,$File::Find::name
 }, "."
 );

 foreach(@wanted_files){
 print CEL $CEL_dir."$_\n";
 }close (CEL);
```

But it is giving the error:-

```
FATAL ERROR:Error opening cel file: /media/home/folder
/./44754.CEL
Read 2 cel files from: cel_files.txt

FATAL ERROR:Can't read file: '/media/home/folder
/./folder/44754.CEL'
```

where I am wrong or what modification is required in this script.

Comment: These error messages don't come from your Perl script. Either you are not posting the code you are running, or the error comes from somewhere else. Also note that the error messages seem to contain a newline between `folder` and `/./`. Maybe that's the source of the problem. Please [edit] your post and post the relevant code and/or the correct error messages.

Comment: @Corion This is the same code and error nothing change.

Comment: You claim the script outputs `FATAL ERROR:Error opening cel file` somewhere. That string is nowhere in your script and Perl does not produce such error messages. So, please check again. Also, if you are running on Windows, using `chomp` will not remove all whitespace from the end of the directory names in `CEL`. Why do you write the names to a file just to read them again?!

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: I would also recommend some consistent indentation. This code is quite unreadable.

Comment: Where are `$input_file` and `$output_file` used? I gather from your code that `$fullspec` is supposed to be the same as the input file?!???

Comment: Why does your script first write to a file (`$cel_files`) and then read that exact same file in again? Why don't you use the information collected in `@wanted_files` directly?

Comment: and then your write in a temp file the exact same contents you wrote to the first file?!?!?!?!? Sorry, your code makes absolutely *no sense*...

Comment: @StefanBecker I am new with Perl. So my code is little long.  output file will use further in program. and $fulspec = $input_file

Comment: You can't expect people to answer your question if your code makes no sense.

Comment: I think a major problem with your logic is that you don't know arrays and use lines in files instead. Whenever you write lines into a file, push them into an array instead: `push @my_lines, $line` instead of `print CEL, "$file\n"`. Then, use `for my $line (@my_lines) { ...` instead of `for my $line (<CEL>) { ...`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to ignore all the stuff from the OP code that seems to be unnecessary.

Instead my answer concentrates on the only piece that actually does seem to do something: the anonymous function passed to `find()`. Based on that I determine that the OP wants to search for files with the same name as given on the command line, starting at the current directory.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my($match) = @ARGV;
die "usage: $0 <file name to match>\n"
    unless defined $match;

# file search
find({
        wanted   => sub {
            print "$File::Find::name\n"
                if (-f $_) && ($_ eq $match);
        },
     },
     '.'
);

exit 0;
```

Example usage:

```sh
$ ./R.pl some_file_name_to_find >cel_files.txt
```

---

The question remains: **WHY?** The same can be achieved on the shell command line with:

```sh
$ find . -type f -name some_file_name_to_find >cel_files.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't have too much knowledge about programming and I am learning it so it may be vary easy in Shell.

Comment: @ritz Well, is my answer correct, i.e. did I guess what your program is supposed to do? If yes, then please up-vote and accept it. Otherwise I would suggest to rephrase or close your question.

Answer (score 0):

After removing $CEL_dir It is working as expected

```
use File::Find;
my @wanted_files;
find(
 sub{ 
     -f $_ && $_ =~ $files  
           && push @wanted_files,$File::Find::name
 },"$ARGV[0]"
);

foreach(@wanted_files){
print CEL "$_\n"; # remove $CEL_dir
}close (CEL);
```